# Pandas select columns using slicing and integer index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, slice

I am trying to select columns 2 and 4: (column 4 till the end):

```
df3.iloc[:, [2, 4:]]
```

> File "", line 1
>   df3.iloc[:, [2, 4:]]
>   ___________^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I get an error message obviously. There are many columns after col 4 so writing something like this does not feel right: [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...]

Is there any other quick way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `range` with [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df3)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

cols = ([2] + list(range(4,df3.shape[1])))
print (cols)
[2, 4, 5]

print (df3.iloc[:,cols])
   C  E  F
0  7  5  7
1  8  3  4
2  9  6  3
```

Another solution with [`numpy.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
cols1 = np.r_[2, np.arange(4,df3.shape[1])]
print (cols1)
[2 4 5]

print (df3.iloc[:,cols1])
   C  E  F
0  7  5  7
1  8  3  4
2  9  6  3
```